# How can I convert an indexed JavaScript object to an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object that looks like this:

```
obj = {
"price": {0: "10.00", 1: "15.00", 2: "6.00"},
"serialNumber": {0: 1000, 1: 2000, 2: 3000}
}
```

I'm trying to convert it into an array of objects so I can do `obj.map((obj, idx)=>{//display obj.price and obj.serialNumber//})`, so I want to convert `obj` into an array like this:

```
obj_array = [{"price":"10.00", "serialNumber": 1000}, {"price":"15.00", "serialNumber": 2000},{"price":"6.00", "serialNumber": 3000}]
```

I initially used `array = Object.values(obj['serialNumber'])` to just get serialNumber, but due to the way `Object.values` works, I can't just do `array = Object.values(obj['serialNumber','price'])` to get both. The values() function will ignore the serialNumber field and just make an array of prices. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` with `Object.entries()` to convert your object to array.

```js
const obj = { "price": { 0: "10.00", 1: "15.00", 2: "6.00" }, "serialNumber": { 0: 1000, 1: 2000, 2: 3000 } },
      result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((r,[key, value]) => {
        Object.values(value).forEach((val, i) => {
          r[i] = {...(r[i] || {}), [key]: val};
        });
        return r;
      },[]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.